# Reuse properties and constraints and behavior for domain classes with no inheritance

Tags: grails, grails-orm, traits

We are dealing with a lot of problems because of inheritance. We did all our domain classes extend from a Component.groovy, that has common properties.
We need to get rid of that class, but we want to keep the common properties in only one place if it possible in the code (there are no problems in creating the columns on each table).
I'm trying to do this with a Trait, but I can't make it work. Important: We are using Grails 2.5.2 :(

Our current code is (keeping it simple):

```java
abstract class Component {

    Date createdDate = new Date()
    Long createdById = 0
    ....

    static constraints = {
        createdDate nullable: false
        createdById nullable: false
        ...
    }

    static mapping = {
        tablePerHierarchy false
    }

    def beforeInsert() {
        def user = Holders.grailsApplication.mainContext.getBean('springSecurityService').currentUser
        if (user) {
            createdById = user.id
            createdDate = new Date()
        }
    }

    def beforeUpdate() {
        ...
    }
}

class User extends Component {
    ...
}
```

Is there a chance to not rewrite every property/constraint/mapping/beforeInsert, etc, in each subclass?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a chance to not rewrite every
>   property/constraint/mapping/beforeInsert, etc, in each subclass?

Yes, but the right solution depends on understanding your domain.  You could have sophisticated AST transformations, you could use aggregation instead of inheritance, you can use shared constraints, you can use event listeners instead of `beforeInsert`, `beforeUpdate` etc.  There are many options.